# Method to count headers from web request?

Tags: c#

I made a program in VB.net a few years back which counted headers from web requests and if it matched 10 it would do something else it would continue checking.

I'm now trying to transfer the program to C# and extend the program, does C# have a similar method? I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webheadercollection.count?view=net-6.0) but I am struggling to implement it.

For reference, this is my visual basic code:

```
    Sub CheckLink(ByVal link As String)
    Try
        If link.Length >= 3 Then
            Dim web As New WebClient
            web.Headers.Add("user-agent", " Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0")
            Dim t As Byte() = WC.DownloadData("https://www.google.com")
            Dim headers As WebHeaderCollection = WC.ResponseHeaders
            WC.Dispose()
            If headers.Count = 10 Then
                Msgbox("Correct")
            Else
                // Do nothing
            End If
    End Try
End Sub
```

Is there a method for C#? thank you!

EDIT:

I've tried implementing it into my C# but I don't think the user agent is correct as it's not outputting. I have tested the header count on a basic plaintext website without the user agent and it outputted the correct header count but I think that websites with javascript need the user agent provided otherwise it doesn't return the HttpWebResponse. Where have I gone wrong?

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Header count: ");
        

        HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://passport.twitch.tv/usernames/sdjkf3jk");
        myHttpWebRequest.UserAgent = " Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0";
        HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        WebHeaderCollection myWebHeaderCollection = myHttpWebResponse.Headers; 

        Console.WriteLine(myWebHeaderCollection.Count); // Test write to see if outputting
    }
```

Comment: "Does C# have a similar method?" - this is VB.NET code, not "classic" VB code, so you're dealing with the same `WebClient` as in C#, and the same `WebHeaderCollection` as in C#. So `if(headers.Count == 10) { MessageBox.Show("Correct"); }`

Comment: You'll note that in the documentation you linked, there is a [dropdown labelled C#](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qw7CD.png). If you [change it to VB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uw0mo.png), it shows the exact same information about the exact same object, albeit with VB.NET syntax.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Have updated to .net now. I'll look into the documentation now. Thanks